# Google cloud - Deployment manager: creating External table using hive partitioning

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-deployment-manager

I'm trying to create an external table with partitioning on Hive using the Deployment manager (.yaml). My code is like this, but it is not returning the key.

```
resources:       
  - name: test
    type: bigquery.v2.table
    properties:
      storageClass: STANDARD
      location: us-east1
      datasetId: testingdataset #id do dataset
      tableReference:
        projectId: project #id do projeto
        tableId: testing
        description: Table test
      schema:
        fields:
        - mode: nullable 
          name: Test1
          type: STRING

        - mode: nullable 
          name: Test2
          type: STRING

        - mode: nullable
          name: Test3
          type: STRING

      externalDataConfiguration:         
        hivePartitioningOptions:
          mode: CUSTOM
          sourceUriPrefix: gs://testing-bucket/{dt:STRING}
          fields: dt
        sourceUris: 
            - gs://testing-bucket/dt=*/testing.csv
        sourceFormat: CSV
        csvOptions: 
          fieldDelimiter: ;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read this link and then improve your question to show your work, the problem, expected results, and error messages. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: please provide me the steps/doc that you followed. are you getting any error message when not returning the key?Please also remove the sensitive information like bucket name and etc.

Comment: I used this doc: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables?hl=pt-br.
No error message appears, but does not return to Key.